# Project build settings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, settings

Is there a way I can save the build settings for a project, and then import those settings into another project? I'm specifically interested in doing this for the C/C++ Build settings here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. Unfortunately, build details are very plugin-specific (i.e. specific to plugins offering build functionality: JDT, CDT or whatever you use).

However, there is a dirty method to try to migrate build settings: just copy and then change/adjust corresponding eclipse files. Usually, build settings are scattered out in different files in '.settings' folder in you project. Keep in mind, that doing this way you need to understands how settings are stored.